# Do we have any scope to kill a command if it runs more than 2 secs

Tags: command-line, batch-file, process

Do we have any scope to kill a command if it runs more than 2 secs in batch scripting?
I have tried ptime but it was just showing how much time that a process will take to run.

Example: If I wanted to run a XXX.exe file if that is running more than 2 seconds we want that to be killed. sometimes that process might be hanged then the script need to kill that process or call any funcion to kill a process.

If you help me soon It can say u a 10k Thanks :)...

Comment: did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I only know a PowerShell way, but you can call it from cmd like this:

```
powershell "$y = ps 'acrotray' ; if ((New-TimeSpan -Start $y.StartTime | select -expand Seconds) -ge 2) { $y.kill() }"
```

write your ProcessName instead of `acrotray`